# How to achieve MS-Excel behaviour using wxDataViewListCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'd like to edit items of wxDataViewListCtrl and I also want the item which displays keywords non-empty when edit is done. When the item is empty, I want my program behaves as MS-Excel, i.e. you cannot save, close, switch, etc. when the value of a cell is invalid.

**Current Implementation**

I check if the item is empty in EVT_DATAVIEW_ITEM_VALUE_CHANGED. But the problem is the click event when the save button is pushed reaches before EVT_DATAVIEW_ITEM_VALUE_CHANGED, since the focus of the edit control is killed only if the wxFileDialog is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the user from leaving the cell even when it's empty, you simply can't (nor should try) to trap him like this. You can however ensure that the cell always has some valid value by setting it to some default if it's empty or invalid in your model overridden `SetValue()` method.